# Entering tags like "</3" in a comment box disturbs my page HTML

Tags: php, html

I have an issue that if user enters html tags in comment box then when it displays the comment from database , it disturbs my page html because it contains html tags itself , where as I have to allow the user to enter anything.

**For example:**

When I enter this string in a comment box:

```
abcd</3efgh<ijkl/mnop3qrst/3uvwx</yz
```

It disturbs my whole HTML because it contains tags like **`</3`**

Can someone suggest me a solution please?

Comment: *What* comments area? How is the content of the comments area interpreted on the server-side? **Where is your code?**

Comment: [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: It is a general question. If you enter such tags in database and fetch it back it will disturb the page design

Answer (score 0):

Escape the characters, using PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Also, for future reference, it's helps to post your code with your question, along with what you've tried and why it didn't work.